# Differences in image width units between 0.13 and 0.14

Tags: php, phpword

On my project, using PHPWord 0.13, I add images this way:

```
$section->addImage(public_path('img/picture.jpg'),['width'=>Converter::cmToPixel(16)]);
```

It works like charm, but now I updated to 0.14 and noticed that images are larger than before.
To emulate the same behaviour, I should change it to:

```
$section->addImage(public_path('img/picture.jpg'),['width'=>Converter::cmToPoint(16)]);
```

cmToPixel -> cmToPoint

Why is this? I have lots of files with lots of images using cmToPixel.
What can I do to "fix" this by doing something global?

Also it happens with addLine
thanks

Comment: this was changed in order to fix https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/224, I'm afraid there's no global property you can set to fix this